# Hide dropdown menu when clicked - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation bar in my website and all the links are loading a content in a container through AJAX.

Now, I need to hide the dropdown menu when a link is clicked. That's not the normal behavior of bootstrap.

Here's my code in the fiddle.

`$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").prev().toggle();
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/fw7vh/158/

I recently browsed into existing answers but it removes the dropdown button. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    var menu = $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu");
    $(menu).css('display','none');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(menu).css('display','');
    },200);
});
```

Comment: neat hack. thanks! I will test it with the real site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this might help you.

```
    $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: The problem with that code is when i hover back to the link, it no longer shows the submenu. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with replacing your code

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").prev().toggle(); 
});
```

with this

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() { 
   $(document.body).click(); 
});
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fw7vh/162/)

Comment: Hi. Let me clarify. When I hover the dropdown, it shows a dropdown menu. If the user clicks the menu, it should hide the dropdown. From my previous code, it hides it perfectly but doesn't show again when hovered.

Comment: Yes, I did. I click a link in the submenu and it doesn't disappear. :(

Comment: just try to move your mouse from menue